# Is gmp.h or glpk the issue? How can I fix this error?

Tags: c++, gmp, glpk

I am trying to `make` the [Hypro](https://github.com/hypro/hypro) package. I am receing an error message (see below) and I cannot make out whether gmp.h or glpk is the issue. How can I fix this?

After I pulled the github repository, installed the dependencies, and created the build folder, I executed `cmake ..` and `make resources`. `make` then produced the below error.
I checked for the gmp.h installation, deinstalled it and re-installed it with `brew install gmp`.

I run a MacBook Pro, M1, 2020, with macOS 14.0.
I also updated XCode.

```
(base) lars@unterwegs-3 build % make                  
[  0%] Performing configure step for 'glpk'
CMake Error at /Users/lars/phd/hypro/build/resources/src/glpk-stamp/glpk-configure-Release.cmake:37 (message):
  Command failed: 1

   '/Users/lars/phd/hypro/resources/glpk-5.0/configure' '--prefix=/Users/lars/phd/hypro/build/resources/src/glpk-build' '--with-gmp' '--with-pic' 'CPPFLAGS=-fPIC' '--disable-shared' '--disable-dl' '--enable-static'

  See also

    /Users/lars/phd/hypro/build/resources/src/glpk-stamp/glpk-configure.log

-- Log output is:
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a race-free mkdir -p... ./install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether the compiler supports GNU C... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to enable C11 features... none needed
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking build system type... arm-apple-darwin23.0.0
checking host system type... arm-apple-darwin23.0.0
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /usr/bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... no
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 786432
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking how to convert arm-apple-darwin23.0.0 file names to arm-apple-darwin23.0.0 format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert arm-apple-darwin23.0.0 file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... no
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for mt... no
checking if : is a manifest tool... no
checking for dsymutil... dsymutil
checking for nmedit... nmedit
checking for lipo... lipo
checking for otool... otool
checking for otool64... no
checking for -single_module linker flag... no
checking for -exported_symbols_list linker flag... yes
checking for -force_load linker flag... yes
checking for stdio.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... yes
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fno-common -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fno-common -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... no
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... darwin23.0.0 dyld
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... no
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking for exp in -lm... yes
checking for sys/time.h... yes
checking for gettimeofday... yes
checking for gmp.h... no
configure: error: gmp.h header not found

CMake Error at /Users/lars/phd/hypro/build/resources/src/glpk-stamp/glpk-configure-Release.cmake:47 (message):
  Stopping after outputting logs.

make[2]: *** [resources/src/glpk-stamp/glpk-configure] Error 1
make[1]: *** [resources/CMakeFiles/glpk.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: [Installing a C/C++ library with homebrew on M1 Macs](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/414622)

Comment: Thanks @paleonix! I was able to set the environment accordingly, but the error from above has not changed at all.
In `env` the path entry consists of `PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/opt/homebrew/include:/opt/homebrew/lib` besides the other usual entries.

Comment: It's a library, and CMake is searching the header. So `PATH` is irrelevant. It's used when searching for executables. `CPATH` is what needs to be set to (or better appended with) `.../include`. And for finding libraries `LIBRARY_PATH` needs to be set to `.../lib`. Have you even read the answer?

Comment: Thanks @paleonix! I had no idea how to add an environment variable. Through another article I was pointed towards editing `.zshrc` and eventually did not pay attention that `CPATH` and `LIBRARY_PATH` had to be appended. I did so now and it all works. Thanks a million from a fellow PhD student!